# How to check if currently logged in user is admin or not

Tags: sitecore

How can I check in sitecore that the current user is an administrator?

something like:

```
if(User.Current.Name == "extranet\Admin")
// then do some thing ??
```

Comment: If you need to check they are an admin in the Sitecore shell then use Marek's solution,if you want to check if a user has a specific role then you can use the IsInRole method.

Comment: @IanGraham is right. Also Christian's answer is correct as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User` class has built in property `IsAdministrator`:

```cs
    Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator
```

Comment: Just as a note: This will check if the user has the checkbox 'Is Administrator' enabled for their account. It does not check if they are in any sort of administrator role. If you are specifically checking if a user is part of a particular group, you should use IsInRole.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just call `Sitecore.Context.IsAdministrator`

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you wanted:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole("extranet\admin")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
var result = Sitecore.Context.User.IsAdministrator;
```

If admin is logged in result is true, otherwise result is false.

Answer (score 0):

A remark  \ is a escape in c# use `"extranet\\Admin"` and the CMS admin is sitecore\admin

I assum you need to know your extranet admin. it's a good idea to do role-based, there can be multiple admin's (not sure if the IsAdministrator property is good working for a extranet)

```
Sitecore.Context.User.IsInRole("extranet\\your extranet admin rol");
```

If you do not have a Extranet admin rol and don't want it, then you can use what you already have `if (Sitecore.Context.User.Name == "extranet\\Admin")`